# Map FirebaseUser to custom User object

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a Flutter app in which I'm listening to auth changes from Firebase to display the correct screen, using a StreamProvider. What I would like to do is to map the FirebaseUser to a custom User object, which would be retrieved from Firestore, to have it accessible from anywhere in the widget tree.

Is there any way to achieve this?

What I'm doing right now:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<FirebaseUser> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(...)
```

Comment: Create **models** to convert data into Dart object and you are using Provider for the state management so simply extends the models with **ChangeNotifier** and get the data from whenever you want to :D

Comment: wondering if you ever found a solution!

Comment: @Karen unfortunately no, it was a small project that got put aside ^^

Comment: no worries, it took me a few days and nights but I finally figured it out. I'll write up a solution in a bit to help others and if you ever revisit your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart to combine and merge the Firebase auth user and Firestore user streams.

For the auth stream, I'm using `userChanges()` to listen to all user updates. `flatMap()` takes the auth stream, converts it to a firestore stream and combines it with the firestore stream so now we are listening to both auth changes and firestore changes.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
      value: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().flatMap(
          (firebaseUser) => DatabaseService(uid: firebaseUser.uid).userData)),
      child: MaterialApp(...)
```

**database.dart**

```
class DatabaseService {
    final String uid;
    DatabaseService({this.uid});

    // get firestore user stream and convert each item into your user object (UserModel in my example)
    Stream<UserModel> get userData {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots()
            .map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data()));
```

**user_model.dart**

```
class UserModel {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    UserModel({this.field1, this.field2});

    // using factory to create an instance of UserModel
    factory UserModel.fromMap(Map data) {
        return UserModel(field1: data['field1'], field2: data['field2']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, start with the custom model and decide what you would like to have, in this case I will simply have the *uid*

###User model###

```
 class CurrentUser {
      final String uid;
    
      CurrentUser ({ this.uid });
    }
```

###AuthService###

```
// Create user object based on FirebaseUser
  CurrentUser _customModelForFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? CurrentUser (uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth changed user stream
  Stream<CurrentUser > get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
      .map(_customModelForFirebaseUser)
  }
```

###My App###

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<CurrentUser >.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can access it from anywhere, like so:

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        final user = Provider.of<CurrentUser>(context);
}
```

Comment: I understand, but my User model is built based on the result of a Firestore query for the given Firebase UID. How do I make it so that when the auth status changes, the stream gets mapped to some async value?

Comment: You can check by using an *if/else* whenever there is an auth change, for example, `if (user == null) {} else { map (stream) }`

Comment: attempting the code in the AuthService produces the error "The class 'User' doesn't have a default constructor. Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'User'"
How does one solve such an error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you can't use `User` anymore because that's a default type now in the Firebase Service. `User` used to be `FirebaseUser`, so now simply change the name.